# Returning a success or failure from ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have some code executed in PHP after meeting some criteria through if/then statements which looks something like this:

```
if(in_array($ext,$video)&&($ext!=="mp4")){
    exec("ffmpeg -i ".$fileName.".".$ext." -s 640x360 ".$fileName.".mp4");
    /*
    if(successful){
        unlink($fileName.$ext);
        $status="Video entry approved. File converted.";
    }
    */
}
```

As you can see, the issue I'm having is trying to figure out what should go in place of `if(successful)`. The point of this section of the code is to check the files extension against an array of known extensions that are in video format, and that aren't already in the mp4 format. If it passes this check, ffmpeg should run and convert to mp4.

So a few questions here. Firstly, how can I return a status to tell me if it is converting, succeeded, or failed? Secondly, how can this be run asynchronously? That is, if I wanted to convert multiple files, would I be able to do so? Would I be able to limit ffmpeg to ensure it does not take up all of my server's processing power and inadvertently bring the site to a grinding halt?

Or is there a better way to go about converting files than this? I'm pretty sure my method must be crude.

EDIT: In addition to this, how does one run ffmpeg in the background, so that the page can be closed, and/or another instance from the same page can be started up by the user for multiple simultaneous conversions? Is it possible to include a real-time progress status of each conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I like your use of exec.  Did you happen to notice the php.net entry for that command?  It's signature looks like this:

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

You're using the $command parameter, but not $output or $return_var.  So you basically have two choices here:
1 - Add the $output parameter to your exec command and print_r.  Once you know the return you can use that information to help you with your logic.  (The $output parameter is filled with any output that would have printed to the console had you run the command on the console.)  Note that you may have to add the option `-loglevel 'verbose'` to see useful output.

```
exec("ffmpeg -i -loglevel 'verbose' ".$fileName.".".$ext." -s 640x360 ".$fileName.".mp4", $my_output_var);

print_r($my_output_var);<br>
```

2- Add $output and $return_var, then check to make sure $return_var is equal to 0 (which means the command executed successfully).  A list of return vars can be found [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html.):

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ".$fileName.".".$ext." -s 640x360 ".$fileName.".mp4", $my_output_var, $var);

if($var == 0){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I'll get around to trying that when I'm not busy, but in the meantime, I don't suppose you know anything regarding the edit at the bottom of my question?

Comment: Add a space and an ampersand at the very end of your command.  That will tell Linux you want it run in the background: exec("ffmpeg -i ".$fileName.".".$ext." -s 640x360 ".$fileName.".mp4 &");

Comment: By the way, you might need to modify your flow for a more reliable user experience: To begin, I would separate this application into three scripts - one that accepts user requests, one that reports on the status of requests, and one that does the processing work.  The script that accepts user requests would write the request data to a database.  The script that reports on requests would read from the database.  The script that does the work would do the work, and then update a row in the database.  It would run on a crontab.

Comment: Currently my code is `exec("/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -loglevel 'verbose' -i '".$fileNameIn.".".$ext."' '".$fileNameOut.".flac' </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/var/www/resources/ffmpegAudio.log &",$ffmpegOutput);` which outputs to a log file, but I see no progress information in it. Also, this is an admin feature, rather than a user one, if that makes a difference. User experience isn't a priority if it makes things overly complicated for me.